# Disable multiple "editors"? aka how do I fix my project explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently whenever I open up a new file, from my understanding it's creating another editor with it's own instance of the project explorer.

I'm all for multiple editors, however it drives me nuts having multiple project explorers. (This equally drives me nuts in xcode). For me, ideally the project explorer would work the same way it does in Visual Studio. i.e. you open a new file into a new, what I will call "tab", and the state of the project explorer stays the same. If I scroll my project explorer, expand / collapse a directory and open a new tab, that explorer stays in the exact same state it was in.

Is that possible in VS Code? Is there a setting I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: VS Code is based on files and folders. Is the file you are opening in a subfolder of the folder you have open in VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
"explorer.autoReveal": false
```

This should disable automatically revealing the active file in the explorer

Comment: Thank you so much! This is totally the flag I was looking for! Now if only I could do the same in xcode!